# Error in Android Studio with SQLITE database: SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to working with SQLite and can't get past a ConstraintException. I understand that it's trying to tell me that I am entering a null value into a column that I declared "not null", but that column doesn't exist. I previously had a typo "pone" instead of phone, but when I fixed it, I still ran into the error. So, I deleted all references to a phone value as well as the phone column in the database, saved, synched, restarted, and still got the error. Included are screenshots.

Error message:

[image: error message]

Code:

[image: database helper]

Thanks!

Comment: Clear your app data and try again. Odds are, you're still using the database with the typo.

Comment: I think you are inserting value **null** into the column but you have already defined that value must **not null**
Post your code here..

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that your table has not yet been dropped since the change. You only drop on upgrade and not on create.